# Parse JSON column using Presto

Tags: sql, json, presto

I have a table in Presto that looks like

| Date | Rates |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | {"USD":"725.275","GBP":"29.275000000000002","CAD":"0.713352"} |
| 1/2/2022 | {"USD":"745.275","GBP":"40.275000000000002","CAD":"0.813352"} |

What I'd like it to resemble as output of the query is:

```
Date    Currency    Rate
1/1/2022    USD 725.275
1/2/2022    USD 745.275
1/1/2022    GBP 29.275
1/2/2022    GBP 40.275
1/1/2022    CAD 0.713352
1/2/2022    CAD 0.813352
```

But can't seem to figure it out using the their [documentation.](https://trino.io/docs/334/functions/json.html#cast-from-json)

Comment: I've tried json_extract_scalar but don't see a way to leverage without manually typing in "json_extract_scalar(Rates, '$.USD')....for each rate. In reality I have a lot of them, so manually typing this out is not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Rates` is column of `JSON` type (otherwise use `json_parse`) and you don't want to handle every currency "manually" with `json_extract_scalar` (`json_extract_scalar(Rates, '$.USD')`, `json_extract_scalar(Rates, '$.GBP')`, ...) - common way to handle such "dynamic" json is to cast it to `map` (for example `map(varchar, double)` in this case) and use [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
WITH dataset ( Date,Rates) AS (
    VALUES  ('1/1/2022', json '{"USD":"725.275","GBP":"29.275000000000002","CAD":"0.713352"}'),
            ('1/2/2022', json '{"USD":"745.275","GBP":"40.275000000000002","CAD":"0.813352"}')

) 

--query
select date, currence, rate
from dataset
cross join unnest(cast(rates as map(varchar, double))) t(currence, rate)
```

Output:

| date | currence | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | CAD | 0.713352 |
| 1/1/2022 | GBP | 29.275000000000002 |
| 1/1/2022 | USD | 725.275 |
| 1/2/2022 | CAD | 0.813352 |
| 1/2/2022 | GBP | 40.275 |
| 1/2/2022 | USD | 745.275 |

Comment: This did trick! Rates was not JSON, so had to wrap in 'json_parse'.