# how to get the first tuple in a string column using presto

Tags: sql, arrays, tuples, presto, varchar

so i am having a column in the table, the data type of the column is varchar, but it contains an array of tuples, so what I need is to extract the first tuple of the array in the table

this is the original table

| userid | comments |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [["hello world",1],["How did you",1],[" this is the one",1]] |
| 2 | [["hello ",1],["How ",1],[" this",1]] |

and this is what i am looking for , please notice that the datatype of 'comments' column is **varchar**.

| userid | comments |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello world |
| 2 | hello |

Comment: I have no way to test it, so here's a comment giving advice: Parse the string as JSON and use `json_extract_scalar()` https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html  For example, something like `json_extract_scalar(json_parse(comments), '$[0][0]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`json_extract_scalar`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract_scalar) should do the trick:

```sql
WITH dataset (userid, comments) AS (
    VALUES  (1, json '[["hello world",1],["How did you",1],[" this is the one",1]]'),
            (2, json '[["hello ",1],["How ",1],[" this",1]]')
)

--query
select userid,
    json_extract_scalar(comments, '$[0][0]')
from dataset
```

Output:

| userid | comments |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello world |
| 2 | hello |

Note that it will allow to extract only single value, if you want multiple values you will need to do some casting (similar to one done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72262711/parse-json-column-using-presto/72262926#72262926) but using arrays, for example `array(json)`).